# is it possible to select an object of a Material UI select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is in react with material ui, building a select field with a TextField and a ManuItem component.
my code:

```
{data.category?.map((category) => (
     <MenuItem
         key={category.id}
         value={{
             id: category.id,
             percentage: category.percentage,
        }}
     >
         {category.name}
     </MenuItem>
```

but is giving me this console warning:
Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `[object Object]` for the select...

any idea?

Comment: Can you share some more code (and a sample input that is being used) because as what I have tried based on the question asked, I don't see any warning. Checkout this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-twcpm?file=/demo.js:0-1845)

Comment: this is a fork of your code with the case mentioned https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-22qr3?file=/demo.js, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because TextField accepts only one of the values from the list. In this case, list items are objects and not strings so they don't match and hence the warning.

Here's a working [codesandbox with the second approach (using objects as values)](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6x58f?file=/demo.js:1140-1262)

1. You can either change the value of the items to strings and set the value of TextField as one of the string values.

   ```
          <MenuItem
            key={d.id}
            value={d.name}
          >
   ```
2. Or you must stringify the json objects as an HTML attribute cannot hold a JSON Object. So, it tries to generate a valid string by using toString() method on object that generates '[object Object]' as its value. Therefore, if you stringify the object, your list item will have a stringified value of the entire object (please note if the object is very large this may not be the optimal approach).

   ```
          <MenuItem
            key={d.id}
            value={JSON.stringify({
              id: d.id,
              percentage: d.percentage,
              name: d.name
            })}
          >
   ```

And add value prop to TextField

```
      <TextField
        id="outlined-select"
        select
        required
        label="Select"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={handleChange}
        helperText="Please select a value"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        value={selectState || ""} // THIS IS NEEDED
        defaultValue={""}
      >
```

Comment: wow, this is very nice! thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this is the correct answer, please mark it as well.